# Excel sorting questioin

Tags: excel, sorting, filtering

[image]

I have the data above and I was wondering if there is a way to search for records whos parameters are

tapped: Yes
packageName: com.zeus.jackpot

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply filter the data by adding filters to the header row (under Data in excel 2010) and typing some or all of the string.

If you need to do it in a formula use the FIND() function eg

=FIND("tapped: Yes packageName: com.zeus.jackpot",I2)

It will return the start position of the string if it finds it otherwise it will return an #N/A error. You could trap this so:

=IF(ISNA(FIND("tapped: Yes packageName: com.zeus.jackpot",I2)),"not found","found")

This assumes that the cell in the params field is a string.

I'm assuming the params field is in column I as there is no column header above that field (obviously change "not found" and "found" to something more appropriate, eg 0 or 1).

If I've got the wrong idea please correct my assumptions or supply more info, ta.

Comment: Wow that was so much easier then I was expecting it to be.